Labelling with unique value and concat
I would like to configure the labels so that they can meet these conditions:

a label by unique "MeasurementPointName"
for each unique value "MeasurementPointName" + "JarNam", display the values ​​"MeasurementPointName" + "JarFrom"+"JarTo" + all "ParameterName"+"ParamaterMeasuredValue"

Attribute table:

Expected result :
F12 (20-50)
Benzo(k)fluoranthène (*) (**) : 3,3 ;
Benzo(ghi)Pérylène : 3,9 ;
Chrysène : 6,8 ;
Benzo(a)pyrène : 7,2 ;
Benzo(b)fluoranthène : 9,6 ;
Fluoranthène : 12 ;

Is this a table with geometries  (does each MeasurementPointName entry in this table have an associated geometry). Or is this just a table without geometries and location of each Measurement Point Name reside in another layer ? Another question, do you have similar MeasurementPointNames with different JarNames or from/to values ?


Each MeasurementPointName entry in this table have an associated geometry. The geometry is the same for the same MeasurementPointName. 2. Yes i may have similar MeasurementPointNames with different JarName and from/to values.


What you can do is:
Add a column to your existing layer to combine Parameter and measurements, you can call it Measure and the formula is the following:
concat(ParameterName,': ',ParameterMeasuredValue)
This will create all the sub-strings with parameter: value

Then create a Virtual layer that will group MeasurementPointName and concatenate the desired Label string.
Create a virtual layer with this query:
select MeasurementPointName,JarName, concat(MeasurementPointName,' (',JarFrom,'-',JarTo,') ',group_concat(Measure,' ,')) as Label, geometry from output_table group by MeasurementPointName,JarName,JarFrom,JarTo,geometry
where Measure is the name of the predefined field, and output_table it the name of your MeasurementPointNames

This layer now has a column with your desired Labels and the related geopetry.



Thanks that's awesome ! Is this a way to include similar MeasurementPointNames with different JarName and from/to values. Exemple : F12 (20-50) Benzo(k)fluoranthène (*) (**) : 3,3 ; Benzo(ghi)Pérylène : 3,9 ; F12 (50-90) ; Chrysène : 6,8 ; Benzo(a)pyrène : 7,2 ; Benzo(b)fluoranthène : 9,6 ; Fluoranthène : 12 ;

The "Group by" part will make sure there is one line per combination of anything you ask to "group by". So here it will distinguish combinations of different from/to etc... Let me adapt it to include the geometry as well. Content d'aider ;)

I updated the answer to include the geometry. As you can see, F12 with different from/to results in 2 labels.
